# How to constantly check something in WinForms/C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way that I can have my program constantly checking something while doing other tasks?

I've made a very simple puzzle game (where the user is supposed to align some things) and I want the program to constantly be checking if the user is done with the game or not.

To clarify, I am NOT looking for a solution with a loop like:

```
while(!done){//do stuff}
```

I am looking for something that is possibly built in, if that makes sense, like a function.

Comment: The first thing to learn about good programming is that you should stop thinking in terms of checking or going to get information - let the information come to you.  How will the user tell you that they are done?  Why keep checking?  Why not just wait for them to do something to tell you that they are done?  Users interact with the interface.  Each interaction constitutes an event - all you should be worrying about is what the user has just done and what you are going to do about it.

Comment: It's either a `loop` or a `Timer`. Also you could check it whenever the user changed some part of the puzzle.

Comment: Agreed with @J... - you don't have to be "constantly" checking if the game is over - it can only be over once the user makes a move, which is when you have to do the check - in Windows Forms you have events for that.

Comment: So if I where to put a method call in my main to check if the game is over, it will eventually return true, once the user is done with the game??

Comment: To put it another way, a winforms application is already the most efficient "constantly checking" engine you could hope for - already wrapped up for you into a neat package.  It plugs directly into the operating system, which plugs directly into the hardware, and provides convenient events for you to attach code to.  In a normal user application they are going to be either pushing a key/button or they will move and/or click the mouse.  Winforms controls give you direct access to these events as they happen.  There is no need to "check" - you are told when things happen.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983610%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either using interface/callback or you could create a method to check for the completion of game and pass it to a thread to check.

Example:

```
private Thread checkThread;

private void StartThreadMethod() 
{
        checkThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckGameComplete));
        checkThread.Start(); 
}

public void CheckGameComplete() 
{
          // Do the checking here
          // call checkThread.Stop() once checking is done.
}
```

Note that since this is on another thread and not the ui thread, if the criteria for ending the game is depending on UI, it is not possible to use this without delegating the UI.

Comment: The only way this is the right answer is if this is a realtime game.  If this is a realtime game, it should either not be tagged `winforms`, which is isn't, *or* it should not be made with winforms, which is awfully unsuitable for such a thing.